# How to create multilines command in C#, connect by SSH (RenciSSH) VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssh, connection

:)

I'm working on Visual Studio - I have connect via RenciSSH to ssh in linux servers in my work.
Now I have problem to get output from servers in multiline (below is code):

Authentication in servers:

```
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(txtLog.Text);
PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(txtLog.Text, txtPass.Text);
kauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(txtHost.Text, txtLog.Text, pauth, kauth);

sshclient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);

sshclient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
sshclient.Connect();


txtOutput.Text = txtHost.Text + ":" + Environment.NewLine;

SshCommand sc = sshclient.CreateCommand(@"df -h /home | grep home && ls -l");

txtOutput.Text += sc.BeginExecute() + Environment.NewLine;

sshclient.Disconnect();
```

---

Above there is code where i couldn't get filled output.
And :
When I set only df -h /home | grep home :

```
SshCommand sc = sshclient.CreateCommand(@"df -h /home | grep home)
```

then i have output in my application but when i tried to put two or more commands I have empty output and i dont know why.

There is some issue with connectivity or there is problem with command in Linux?

And second problem, When i set eg :

```
SshCommand sc = sshclient.CreateCommand(@"df -h)
```

I have output in only 1 line and this is not readable. Do you have any tip to have output which i can see in server (row by row)?

Thanks in advance!!!!!